# Conversion between JSON with wrapped structure and pojo with flattended structure

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a JSON structure that incorporates a wrapping level that I don't have in my POJOs. Like so:

JSON:

```
{
    "category1": {
        "cat1Prop1": "c1p1",
        "cat1Prop2": "c1p2",
        "cat1Prop3": "c1p3"
    },
    "category2": {
        "cat2Prop1": "c2p1",
        "cat2Prop2": "c2p2"
    },
    "category3": {
        "cat3Prop1": "c3p1",
        "cat3Prop2": "c3p2",
        "cat3Prop3": "c3p3"
    },
    "category4": {
        "cat4Prop1": "c4p1"
    }
}
```

POJO:

```
public class MyPojo {

    private String cat1Prop1;
    private String cat1Prop2;
    private String cat1Prop3;

    private String cat2Prop1;
    private String cat2Prop2;

    private String cat3Prop1;
    private String cat3Prop2;
    private String cat3Prop3;

    private String cat4Prop1;


    // Getters / setters, etc...
}
```

As you can see, the JSON have a "category" level (that for different reasons I don't want to have in my Pojo).

I'm looking for a way to use Jackson for serializaion/deserialization to handle this in a smooth way.

I'm aware that Jackson has a [@JsonUnwrapped](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation that kind of handles the opposite. I'm also aware that there is a feature request for a ["@JsonWrapped"](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-781) annotation that I think would solve my case.

Thankful for any input or help regarding this, as I have been looking around quite a bit. Also, any suggestions on how this could be accomplished using any other library (like gson, flexjson, etc) is also interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this algorithm:

1. Read JSON as `Map`.
2. Flatten map
3. Use ObjectMapper to convert Map into POJO.

Implementation could looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = mapper.readValue(new File("X:/test.json"), Map.class);
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    result.putAll(entry.getValue());
}

System.out.println(mapper.convertValue(result, MyPojo.class));
```

Comment: Clever! This is only deserialization though. One will also need to add a Serializer. Also, it would be nice to register the code above as a JsonDeserializer, but that seems a bit cumbersome since mapper.convertValue itself invokes the Deserializer.

Comment: Another comment... the JSON structure in the original question incorporates only "1 level" of properties, e.g. there are no nested objects with properties. The deserialization code above only considers  this 1 level of properties.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I did not notice that you need serialization also. In this case I propose you to create POJO class which represents your JSON 1:1 - this is the simplest way which I can imagine. Why you do not want to do it?

Comment: Various reasons. Each of the json "categories" represent very unnatural concepts as regards to the model. I wanted to keep the pojo model clean from these indirections. The pojo model is used in other places where the category-stuff will be quite confusing.

Comment: Anyway, after a lot of hassle I think I'm more or less forced to swallow a few of those pragmatic pills and tweak my pojo model to incorporate categories. I could of course introduce an anti-corruption layer of some sorts, but that would be a bit overkill in my case. Anyway, thanks for the input and suggestions!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. I think you can create two POJO classes: one for JSON representation second for your business model. 1. Deserialize JSON into first POJO, 2. Convert "JSON POJO" into "Model POJO". 3. Use "Model POJO" whenever you want.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant by "anti-corruption layer of some sorts" :)