# how to marshal string(which is unmarshaled from json Object) to json again in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, marshalling, unmarshalling

my json is in below format and for some reason i have to convert it to a string using jackson.

```
{
"responseCode": 200,
"output": [
    {
        "address": {
            "address1": "string",
            "address2": "string",
            "addressId": "1543",
            "city": "string",
            "fxGeocode": "string",
            "houseNumber": "string",
            "isActive": true,
            "postalCode": "string",
            "state": "string",
            "streetName": "string",
            "zip": "string"
        },
        "city": "string",
        "externalIds": [
            {
                "externalId": "string",
                "externalIdDocId": "676273d0-ebf7-4f46-bd5a-e8af09589646",
                "partyRoleExternalIdType": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "string",
        "organizationRoleId": 975,
        "zip": "string"
    },
    {
        "address": {
            "address1": "string",
            "address2": "string",
            "addressId": "1767",
            "city": "string",
            "fxGeocode": "string",
            "houseNumber": "string",
            "isActive": true,
            "postalCode": "string",
            "state": "string",
            "streetName": "string",
            "zip": "string"
        },
        "city": "string",
        "externalIds": [
            {
                "externalId": "string",
                "externalIdDocId": "248badd9-8b5d-4b9d-8c00-055f0afacdfc",
                "partyRoleExternalIdType": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "string",
        "organizationRoleId": 976,
        "zip": "string"
    }
],
"totalCount": 2
}
```

After unmarshalling it to string using jackson it is converted in string as below.

```
{output=[{address={address1=string, address2=string, addressId=1543, city=string, fxGeocode=string, 
 houseNumber=string, isActive=true, postalCode=string, state=string, streetName=string, zip=string}, 
 city=string, externalIds=[{externalId=string, externalIdDocId=676273d0-ebf7-4f46-bd5a-e8af09589646, 
 partyRoleExternalIdType=string}], name=string, organizationRoleId=975, zip=string}, {address= 
{address1=string, address2=string, addressId=1767, city=string, fxGeocode=string, 
 houseNumber=string, isActive=true, postalCode=string, state=string, streetName=string, zip=string}, 
 city=string, externalIds=[{externalId=string, externalIdDocId=248badd9-8b5d-4b9d-8c00-055f0afacdfc, 
 partyRoleExternalIdType=string}], name=string, organizationRoleId=976, zip=string}], 
 responseCode=200, totalCount=2}
```

how to i convert it back to the json format in java? Should i create a class for the same  to marshal it back?

Comment: either you can create a Class and marshal it again or marshal it to a map.

Comment: how can i marshal it to a map?

Comment: You need to show how do you deserialised it. `{output=[{address ...` looks like a result of `toString` method invoked on `Map`.

Comment: @michalZiober  
<convertBodyTo id="_convertBody11To21" type="java.lang.String"/>
 <unmarshal id="abc" ref="jackson"/>


where jackson is=>
<dataFormats>
            <json id="jackson" library="Jackson" 
    unmarshalTypeName="java.util.TreeMap"/>
        </dataFormats>
so map of json is directly converted to string using jackson

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. Create a Java Class and Marshal it to Java Class.

Option 2. Marshal it to HashMap

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

//Convert Map to JSON

```
 map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```

Comment: Much simpler is `readValue(json, Map.class)` with the same practical effect. See [Conversion between JSON with wrapped structure and pojo with flattended structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670852/conversion-between-json-with-wrapped-structure-and-pojo-with-flattended-structur)